# Querying from the new Google Script DB

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying out the new Google App Scripts Data Base and I'm having trouble figuring out a particular type of query.

What is the best way to find if employee 434 has a qualification named "QUAL 1" that was issued after 20050101?  I've included his record below.

```
{
        "id": 434,
        "qualifications": [
            {
                "pathway": "A",
                "name": "QUAL1",
                "issueDate": 20060330,
                "agencyName": "STATE OFFICE 1"
            },
            {
                "pathway": "B",
                "name": "QUAL2",
                "issueDate": 20090305,
                "agencyName": "STATE OFFICE 2"
            }
        ],
        "name": {
            "last": "SMITH",
            "first": "JOHN"
        },
        "type": "hr"
    }
```

Comment: I got excited when I thought Google has released Google Goggle related stuff, then thought twice when I remembered they renamed them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood correctly:

```
function test() {  
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var result = db.query({id: 434})
  var quals = result.next().qualifications;
  var hasQual = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < quals.length; i++) {
    if (quals[i].name == 'QUAL1' && quals[i].issueDate > 20050101) {
      hasQual = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(hasQual);
}
```

Comment: Thanks AdamL, that does the trick.  Is possible to find the value within the array without having to iterate through the array?  For instance, if I wanted to query for everyone who had a value of 'QUAL1' within their record.

Comment: Not that I know of, at least not with the database structure you have set up (the attribute qualifications being an array of objects).  But I could be wrong, I'm quite new at this.  If I were setting this database up, I would have separate records for his qualifications - one record for an employee's basic data like name etc, and then one more record for each qualification, which would make it easier to query.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't currently possible to construct a query that looks for a value within an array. You can file a feature request for that on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).